# Very slow performance on LINQ subquery

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I am facing a performance issue when doing a LINQ subquery in C#.
The query is as follows:

```
var _result = _db.Prices
            .Join(_db.Vendors,
            e => e.VendorId,
            v => v.VendorId,
            (e, v) => new {
                TotalPrice = e.TotalPrice,     
                Vendor = v.Title,               
                AmountPaid = _db.Amounts
                    .Where(p => p.PrId == e.PrId )
                    .GroupBy(p => p.PrId )
                    .Select(grp => (decimal?)grp.Sum(k => k.AmountPaid) ?? 0M)    
                    .FirstOrDefault()  
            });
```

Prices, Vendors and Amounts are Entity Framework objects.

Firstly I am doing a join of Prices to Vendors table on VendorId and on the result I am adding a calculated field AmountPaid. The result is a subquery which returns the sum of AmountPaid column in Amounts table for the given record matched by PrId index.
All the above is returned as a JSON object in ASP.NET web api.

The result of the above for the records in a database is only 1992 rows.
The above command neeeds about 20 seconds to return the result. If I remove the AmountPaid calculation it needs only 1 second.

If I run the equivalent SQL command in SQL Server studio it needs only half a second with the AmountPaid calculation included:

```
SELECT Prices.*, Vendors.Title, 
AmountPaid = (SELECT SUM(AmountPaid) from Amounts where Amounts.PrId = Prices.PrId GROUP BY PrId) FROM Amounts 
INNER JOIN Vendors ON Amounts.VendorId = Vendors.VendorId
```

Is there a way to fix this?
I cannot understand the issue since the SQL command does not have an issue in execution.
Is there an error on the LINQ syntax, or another way to get in LINQ the same result set?

Comment: `If I run the equivalent SQL command in SQL Server studio` <= so its not the equivalent otherwise you would have the same time. You should profile your Sql Server instance to get the actual executed quer(ies). Use that as your benchmark because that is what is being run. If the generated query is not wrong then you need to re-examine your code. If it just runs slow you need to examine your table and/or index structure using the `Execution Plan` as a guide.

Comment: Try rewriting the query such that you left join to the `Amounts` table instead of using a subquery.

Comment: The problem is that you are executing a correlated subquery! LINQ will execute a SEPARATE query for each row to get this data resulting in a LOT of round trips. MSFT hasn't made any improvements to the LINQ2SQL query optimizer in years, I have never tried this so I do not know if EF LINQ would have the same issue or not. When I have had to do something similar, I have either written a single query to do it, or if that is not easy, I have written two queries and then join the result sets in memory (Linq2Objects) and generated my resulting objects

Comment: Firstly thank you all for the immediate response. I have tried two options. Firstly on the above linq query just changing FirstOrDefault() to just First() it performed better dropping from 20secs execution to 8secs. I cant understand the reason although. Secondly I tried juharr's comment, and instead of the subquery I used a GroupJoin to the Amounts table...This performed better to 4,5 secs!

Comment: Couldn't  the subquery just be `_db.Amounts.Where(p => p.PrId == e.PrId ).Sum(p => p.AmountPaid) ?? 0M`.  You also don't need the `Group By` in the SQL.

Comment: "I can't understand the reason". Set up a log on your DbContext and have it write the executed SQL to your Debug console. Take a look at the queries in different states, and learn what the EF parser is doing differently in each scenario.

Comment: Man, I wouldn't want to join your dev team and support this query. Look for simpler ways or just write it in SQL, a sproc, or something.

Comment: Plinq can provide more and much performance than the Linq. This is much faster than ordinary approach. The efficient way is to invoke a stored procedure through entity framework.